# Is it ok to use a low-mileage oil from another car?

Tags: oil, mileage

I usually drive no more than 5000 kilometers a year and I usually change my oil after 7 - 8 months (about 2000 - 2500 kms mileage). According to both manufacturers (car and oil), my 5W-40 Addinol should be changed after 15.000 kms or 12 months (whichever comes sooner). Since I change it earlier than recommended, I thought about giving it for free to my friend to drive **another 4 months** with my used (low mileage) oil. Is it harmful for his car to use my oil after running in my car for only 2000 kms?
I think it is also much better for the environment!

Comment: I find it very difficult to drain the oil from a car without getting dirt and other crud into the drain pan.  That's reason enough to NOT reuse it in another vehicle.

Comment: You should be recycling your used oil anyway.  It should be going to a refiner where they re-refine it and it ends up back as an oil-based product of some sort.

Comment: @jwh20 - What about using a piece of cloth to filter the used oil? (or any other paper filters)

Comment: @jwh20 - It may be possible to make a filter by using the paper inside an oil filter. It does the same thing for the car.

Comment: If that was good enough then oil filters would be made out of pieces of cloth.  No, I would NOT do this.  Perhaps if you don't want your friend to be your friend any longer...

Comment: @jwh20 - What about oil filter? Can I give him my used oil filter?

Comment: You can do anything you want here.  You asked, "...is it harmful...".  In my opinion yes, it is harmful because you cannot guarantee the integrity of this used oil or filter.  The same reasons why YOU don't want to continue using it would be the reasons your friend should not use it.

Comment: Just change your filter and leave the oil in longer. Or you could consider doing the job really well and send a sample of oil away for analysis - done on many expensive engines.

Comment: Done some things to reduce costs, but this must top the cheapskate list.

Comment: The only thing I would ever consider putting used oil into would be a lawnmower, and really that's way more trouble than it's worth.  Motors wear, and the metal particles end up in the oil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only scenario that I would find this acceptable is your friend hasn't changed the oil in a period that grossly exceeds the recommended change interval. If they can't afford to replace their oil, then using yours is a better option than not changing it at all. As others have stated you must be meticulous with the transfer. A clean collection container and funnel are a must. A new filter would be required as the filter may be full of contaminates and in bypass mode. After all this you are replacing oil that is at the end of useful life with oil at 80% of its useful life.

Comment: You should make it clear you mean the recommended interval in *miles or km*, not *time*. Unless you only make short journeys and the engine never fully warms up, oil doesn't "go bad after 12 months" just sitting in the oil sump doing nothing.

Comment: @alephzero - The interval is in km not mph (2000 kms and 8 months). I mostly (90%) drive on the highway and never make short journeys.